# How to call different function on each click on the same button in react

Tags: reactjs

we have a button and have to call different function it is being
clicked. Please suggest some ways in react

```
 const handleClick= ()=>{
 // on first click call func1
func1();
// on second click call func2
 func2();
 // on third click call func3
 func3();
 }


 <button onClick ={()=>{handleClick()}}>Call diff function </button>
```

Comment: You could create a switch case with cases from numbers 1 to 3 and call Math.random to receive a random number from 1 to 3 and then in each case return one of the functions.

Comment: Here is a link that exaplains Math.random https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random and here a link to explain switches in javascript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 0):

First set up the state for component:

`const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0)`

Define your handleClick function with a switch case that updates the state of the click count for each case:

```
const handleClick= () => {

switch(clickCount) {
  case 0:
    /* Call function 1 */
    setClickCount(1)
    break;
  case 1:
     /* Call function 2 */
    setClickCount(2)
    break;
  case 2:
     /* Call function 3 
        you can then reset the state to the 0 if you wanted */
     setClickCount(0)

    break;
  }
}
```

Then set up your button to call the click like so:

`<button onClick ={()=>{handleClick()}}>Button</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Have a state called count. At each click increase the count and by checking
the count and call different functions.

```
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    if (count == 0) {
      console.log("first");
    } else if (count == 1) {
      console.log("second");
    } else if (count == 2) {
      console.log("third");
    }
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
```

Comment: I want to work the button as a zoom-in, zoom-out button, suppose when I Click the zoom-in button then it will zoom to two or three levels and when I zoom out it returns to the previous state. the problem I'm facing is to while zooming out when it 2 nd level zoomed in it should zoom out from the same level. Suggest something.